# How to share data between two VUE Parent App?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have Two different VUE app (dashboardApp & baseApp) in my VUE project i want to share data from one App to another App, and also trigger one modal component from one app to another app, someone please advise how to do that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ruB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a vuex store.
It will be registered on the launch of your application and share state with reactive getters and setters.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

So you will have an action in your store, to mutate a boolean value 'modalopen' from dashboardApp, and a getter, which will be computed in baseApp in your modal.open prop.